# Civilization VI Rise & Fall - My2K cloud save is no longer working

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

I just upgraded Civilization VI to 'Rise & Fall', and the My2K cloud save was working before I installed Rise & Fall - but now it isn't.

I have tried exempting the Steam folder from Windows Defender - and turned off the defender firewall - neither helps. I also tried closing and re-opening the program.

Answer (score 1):

The OP stated in a comment that the issue was resolved the next day for no apparent reason. It might be an issue with the cloud save servers, meaning a possible solution is simply to wait.